# How to pass a struct member pointer to a function?

Tags: c++

How does one go about passing a struct member identifier to a function such that the function can apply an operation to that specified member? The below code example should highlight what I am trying to achieve.

```
struct _struct {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
};
_struct test[5];

void printVar(int index, ??? member) {
    // Print specified member at array element
    printf(test[index].member);
};

int operation(??? member) {
    // Some operation applied to specified member of all array elements
    // eg. Averaging all the readings contained in test[].a
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        total += test.member;
    };
    return total / 5;
};
```

The closest I have found to a solution is described at the below link, whilst the principle is sound in its application it doesn't appear to be the best possible implementation. http://cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/45268/

Comment: You could use a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` instead of a `struct`, and then pass the desired key as the member identifier. Alternatively, you could pass a `std::function` that fetches the desired member from the an argument of type `_struct`.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to have global array `test` and pass either member `a` or `b` to `operation`, so that it returns sum of all `a` or `b` from the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what "pointer to member" is for.

```
struct _struct {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
};
_struct test[5];

void printVar(int index, int _struct::* member) {
    // Print specified member at array element
    printf("%d\n",test[index].*member);
};

int operation(int _struct::* member) {
    // Some operation applied to specified member of all array elements
    // eg. Averaging all the readings contained in test[].a
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        total += test[i].*member;
    };
    return total / 5;
};


int main(){
    printVar(1,&_struct::b);
    operation(&_struct::a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly the solution I needed, thankyou! Funny how no amount of googling reveals what you want sometimes. I had actually even tried what you suggested minus the "int" datatype of the pointer.

Comment: @Scheff Would have done so earlier if the option had been there, I upvoted instead.

Comment: @BranyonApel This might be caused by your rep. Once, I made a question and got an answer immediately, I had to wait 10 minutes but my rep. was already higher... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

How about passing a `std::function` that returns the desired member from a given `_struct`? Like this:

```
#include <functional> // for std::function

struct _struct {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
};
_struct test[5];

void printVar(int index, std::function<int(const _struct&)> getMember) {
    // Print specified member at array element
    printf("%d\n", getMember(test[index])); // note: added missing "%d"
};

int operation(std::function<int(const _struct&)> getMember) {
    // Some operation applied to specified member of all array elements
    // eg. Averaging all the readings contained in test[].a
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        total += getMember(test[i]); // note: added missing [i]
    };
    return total / 5;
};
```

You would use it like this:

```
int get_a(const _struct& s) { return s.a; }
int get_b(const _struct& s) { return s.b; }

int main()
{
    test[0] = {0,1};
    test[1] = {2,3};
    test[2] = {4,5};
    test[3] = {6,7};
    test[4] = {8,9};

    printVar(2, get_a); // prints value of test[2].a
    printVar(4, get_b); // prints value of test[4].b

    const int result_a = operation(get_a); // perform operation on the a members
    const int result_b = operation(get_b); // perform operation on the b members

    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you're familiar with lambdas, you can use them to define `get_a` and `get_b` instead of making them free-standing functions:

```
int main()
{
    test[0] = {0,1};
    test[1] = {2,3};
    test[2] = {4,5};
    test[3] = {6,7};
    test[4] = {8,9};

    const auto get_a = [](const _struct& s) { return s.a; };
    const auto get_b = [](const _struct& s) { return s.b; };

    printVar(2, get_a); // prints value of test[2].a
    printVar(4, get_b); // prints value of test[4].b

    const int result_a = operation(get_a); // perform operation on the a members
    const int result_b = operation(get_b); // perform operation on the b members

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You even could use a lambda instead of `get_a()` and `get_b()`, e.g.: `const int result_a = operation([](const _struct &s) { return s.a; });`

Comment: @Scheff Yep, I was going to use a lambda but wasn't sure if the OP was familiar with them. Updated to add a version that defines them as lambdas.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Thats an interesting way to do it, however @PeterT has exactly the methodology I was chasing. Having to define the separate function for each new parameter you have to grab adds the extra step as such.